# extract dbRDA constrained, unconstrained and total variance as table with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, vegan

I would like to extract from the dbRDA object the constrained, unconstrained and total variance and the proportion rank to save it later as a  table:

here is the example:

```
data(varespec)
data(varechem)
vare.cap <- capscale(varespec ~ N + P + K + Condition(Al), varechem,
                     dist="bray")
```

is it possible to do it with `dplyr`?
Thanks!

Comment: The numbers are in the result object. Just pick up those and put in a "table" (or tibble). The `print` function for the object does so, and you may peek at its code to see how this is done (function `vegan:::print.cca`). I have no idea how to do this with `dplyr`, but you can use base R tools (why do you need to use `dplyr` for a task for which it is not suited?).

Comment: Thanks! I will try with your suggestion!